# UITest does not work within Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I am creating a framework for an iOS and my framework contains UI(Visual Presentation) as well now I want to write XCTest for my framework and I am able write and run the unit Test as we do within application but I am not able run UITest within the framework.

Could anyone help me with this?

your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI tests for iOS that use XCTest

- run in a separate process
- require a host application that runs on the simulator

If you want to UI test your framework, I would create a separate iOS app target that includes and consumes your framework. Then you can create a UI Tests target for this demo application which will assert the framework behavior.